# Calabash-Android - No test server found and Could not sign test server

Tags: android, cucumber

I have followed the steps [here](https://github.com/calabash/calabash-android): I am using the default feature file.When I run: `calabash-android run <some.apk>` then I get the following error:

`No test server found for this combination of app and calabash version. Recreating test    server.`

`jarsigner command: "/bin/jarsigner.exe" -sigalg MD5withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -signedjar test_servers/dc8cdea9d4248b575be609b25c1668fd_0.3.2.apk -storepass android -keystore`

We are using calabash-android 0.3.2

Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATE:** 
I have deleted the calabash settings file, now I am getting different errors:

C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/calabash-android-0.3.3.pre5/bin/calabash-android-build.rb:38:in `block in calabash_build': Could not sign test server

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have a misconfigured `.calabash-settings` file. (all empty values)

You only need to run `calabash-android setup` if your app was signed with another certificate than ~/.android/debug.keystore.

If you do run `calabash-android setup` you need to answer all of the questions.

Comment: Thanks, this did help, however I am now getting a different error, please see the update

Comment: Set your JAVA_HOME as I answered here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/calabash-android/84_aTemdVVI. No reason to cross post. It is wasting people time.